# Grouping SQL Result

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have table like this:

```
id | Name  | Buy
---+-------+-----
 1 | Alice | Apple
 2 | Alice | Banana
 3 | Alice | Apple
 4 | Bob   | Apple
```

How to write one line SQL command that showing result like below?

```
Name  | Apple | Banana
------+-------+-------
Alice |     2 |      1
Bob   |     1 |      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `case when`

```
select Name,sum(case when Buy='Apple' then 1 else0 end) as Apple,
sum(case when Buy='Banana' then 1 else 0 end) as Banana
from yourtable
group by Name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ab22a/2

```
Name    Apple   Banana
Alice   2        1
Bob     1        0
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly.

Comment: @Mawan if it helps then accept my answer